# Document solution Git-like for freezing history + Nextcloud-like for collaboration

Tags: collaboration, version-control, google-drive, nextcloud

## TL;DR

Context: Making quotations for the clients. We are currently using Google Sheets + Google Docs.

Problem: Be able to "freeze a document" against involuntary changes even against the document owner, no matter the permissions of the team.

Can this be done with NextCloud? What other open-source solutions are there appart from Nextcloud?

## Extended version

Our quotations are rather complex and there's a back-and-forth with the team adding, appending, restructuing the documents.

This is our current situation:

**PRICING**

- We have a template in Google Sheets.
- The agent copies the template into a new document in a folder shared with the team.
- We alter and modify to do the calculations for the prices.

**TEXT FOR THE CUSTOMER**

- We have a template in Google Docs.
- We also prepare the text to be sent to the client in a Google Doc.
- Finally the text is copy/pasted into an email and the proposal goes inside the "body" of the email.

**REASONS FOR CONVERTING TO R/O**

- Once this quotation is sent we don't want the spreadsheet to be altered.
- So we wanted it to be marked as "non-modifiable".
- If the client accepts the quotation we need to backtrace "why we set that price" without possibility of error and without the overhead of "looking at the versioning to see if there're are any accidental versions after the one in the date we sent the email".

**MODIFICATIONS AFTER LOCKING**

Nevertheless in some ocasions we need to unlock and do a newer version. If the solution contains "version control" (as Google Sheets have), it is okey to modify the original document.

**ROLLING-BACK ACCICENTAL MODIFICATIONS**

I know that Google Drive is versioned. So if you do accidental modifications you can roll-back to a previous version. But this does not do a real rollback. It "commits again the previous version" and it's kept in the history.

This does not work for us.

I want it to be able to "forbid new history being created".

**EXPLORED SO FAR*

I thought that an open-sourced solution as it is NextCloud it could come with the proper tools.

But this thread https://help.nextcloud.com/t/best-way-to-make-a-folder-or-file-read-only/20390/5 suggests that maybe that's also not possible in Next Cloud.

**IDEAL SOLUTION**

For me the ideal situation would be a solution that behaves as git does:

- Agents modify the document.
- Once the agents arrive to a "good version" then commit it.
- The agents cannot edit it, and if they do, they see it "pending to commit" and could just discard all the changes.
- History is always preserved.

## PURPOSE

- A software that enables collaborative document editing (both word-like docs and excel-like docs)
- That also enables us to protect documents agains editing them.

## OBJETIVE REQUIREMENTS

- Open source
- Web-based with desktop file integration (as Google Drive + Nextcloud do).
- Multi-user granular permissions
- Allows versioning of the documents
- Allows "freezing" a document against accidental changes

(Google Drive + Nextcloud seem to give all except the last one).

## Question

- Can this be done with Nextcloud at oct-2023?
- If not, what software should I explore?